# Is it possible to disable Replace mode in vim?

Tags: vim, replace

Put simply, how can I completely disable Replace mode in vim? I never use Replace mode, but I sometimes end up in it by accident when re-entering Insert Mode. Naturally, I goof up by typing over a few characters before realizing I am in replace mode. So, is there any way to completely disable Replace mode, whether through configuration setup or however?

Comment: For what it is worth, I googled and went through some other questions on SO, and could not find this asked or answered, perhaps I am the only one who doesn't use replace mode and wants to get rid of it, or perhaps my google-fu was too weak.

Comment: How would you replace a single character then ? this is very useful :)

Comment: @Nicolas Viennot You can replace a single character with `r`, this command is not related to replace mode.

Comment: I just don't see the point of disabling some features because one is often typing random things on the keyboard. You still have the undo key if you mess up. (Or ctrl+o if you jumped all around the place and you need to go back where you were).

Comment: @Nicolas: It's a productivity issue. I don't need it, I don't use it, and when I end up in it by accident it costs me time. Maybe over some time I would learn to not end up in it by accident, but I'd prefer to save time.

Comment: @Nicolas: I think it's totally reasonable to make keyboard mistakes less time-consuming to recover from. If you decide you do want to use it, but very rarely, you could always add in a way to bypass/temporarily disable the autocommands as used in ZyX's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot disable replace mode, but you can make autocommands which will change Replace and Virtual Replace modes back to Insert mode:

```
function s:ForbidReplace()
    if v:insertmode isnot# 'i'
        call feedkeys("\<Insert>", "n")
    endif
endfunction
augroup ForbidReplaceMode
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter  * call s:ForbidReplace()
    autocmd InsertChange * call s:ForbidReplace()
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this tomorrow at work and see how it goes.

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Just an extra note to other users, the above would typically go in your .vimrc file, at least that is where I put it for mine.

Comment: How is this better than `imap <Insert> <Nop>`? It seems to have the same effect

Comment: @istepaniuk Really? Using `<Insert>` from insert mode is not the only way to enter replace mode. You should checkout out `:h Replace-mode`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could map R and r to nothing in your .vimrc:

```
map R <C-V><C-V>
map r <C-V><C-V>
```

Edit: or this:

```
map R <Nop>
map r <Nop>
```

Comment: This does nothing when insert mode is changed by `<Insert>` or when you enter replace mode with `gR` (virtual replace).

Comment: And, I forgot, why are you remapping `r`? It is a command for replacing a single character and does not start replace mode.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I didn't choose this answer, because I enter replace mode via <Insert>, so this solution was not applicable

Answer (score 3):

Just add in your .vimrc    `imap <Insert> <Nop>`

That will be enough

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution better. Insert key to enter insert mode works, but replace mode on second insert hit is disabled. Place next two lines into your .vimrc

```
imap <Insert> <Nop>
inoremap <S-Insert> <Insert>
```

(mentioned by garyjohn @ superuser site)

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>I</kbd> key to go into Insert instead of using the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key

That way you will not *re-enter* Insert mode