# How to automatically exit replace mode in vim?

Tags: vim

I've got this series of configuration items in my `.vimrc` which make Vim automatically exit insert mode after a certain duration of inactivity.

```
au InsertEnter * let updaterestore=&updatetime | set updatetime=4000
au InsertLeave * let &updatetime=updaterestore
au CursorHoldI * stopinsert
```

I'm wondering if something similar exists for "replace" mode?

Answer (score 0):

I found that with the above implementation it already works for "replace" mode.

As discussed in [this related Stackoverflow.com answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4112482/86263), replace mode is insert mode with an additional modifier to indicate how the inserts are taking place.  So the snippet in my original question above also works (confirmed through local testing) for replace mode because it doesn't check for the presence or absence of the additional modifier.

*Additional Background*:

[Replace mode](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/vim/modes/) (guide.freecodecamp.org)

> Replace mode allows you replace existing text by directly typing over it. Before entering this mode, get into normal mode and put your cursor on top of the first character that you want to replace. Then press ‘R’ (capital R) to enter replace mode. Now whatever you type will replace the existing text. The cursor automatically moves to the next character just like in insert mode. The only difference is that every character you type will replace the existing one.